# coin collection database. Restricting data

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a coin collector and I would like to place my collection on-line.  I manage only American penny, nickel, dime, quarter, half dollar and dollar coins.  Each coin has a date, a mint mark, a value, condition and a date it was last appraised.  I keep a 3/5 card on each coin where I keep general comments as well.

Create the table named CoinCollection by hand, in your Database, using the following guidelines. I will give you creative freedom outside of my specs.

The mint marks are either D (Denver), P or blank (Philadelphia) , S (San Francisco), O (New Orleans), C C (Carson City).  Allow only these abbreviations.

Conditions are P(Proof), BU (Brilliant Un-circulated), UC (Un-circulated), VF (Very Fine), (F)Fine, G (Good), P (Poor).    Allow only these conditions.

Only P, N, D, Q, HD, D should be allowed as coin types.

Decide what should be filled when a record is added (nulls).

The greatest portion of my collection are in pennies.  Default the data type to a penny.

```
CREATE TABLE CoinCollection
(
   CoinId int Primary Key NOT NULL,
   Manufactured_Date date,
   MintMarks nvarchar(20),
   CONSTRAINT chk_Mintmarks CHECK (Mintmarks IN ('D(Denver)', 'P(Philadelphia)', 'S(San Francisco)', 'O(New Orleans)','C C(Carson City)')),
   Price nvarchar(50),
   Conditions nvarchar(30),
   CONSTRAINT chk_Conditions CHECK (Conditions IN ('P(Proof)','BU(Brilliant Un-Circulated)','UC (Un-circulated)','VF (Very Fine)','F(Fine)','G (Good)','P(Poor)')), 
   Cointypes nvarchar(5),
   CONSTRAINT chk_Cointypes CHECK (Cointypes IN ('P' , 'N','D','Q','HD','D')),
   DEFAULT 'P',
   Appraisal_Date date
) ;
```

This is what I have so far. I keep getting this error.

> Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 0 Incorrect syntax for definition of
>   the 'TABLE' constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below - you need to add `default value` for `cointype` in time of column 
definition

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c44362b39759c12c40ca00b2f607ba7)**

```
CREATE TABLE CoinCollection
(
   CoinId int Primary Key NOT NULL,
   Manufactured_Date date,
   MintMarks nvarchar(20),
   Price nvarchar(50),
   Conditions nvarchar(30),
   Cointypes nvarchar(5) default 'P',
   Appraisal_Date date,
   CONSTRAINT chk_Mintmarks CHECK (Mintmarks IN ('D(Denver)', 'P(Philadelphia)', 'S(San Francisco)', 'O(New Orleans)','C C(Carson City)')),
   CONSTRAINT chk_Conditions CHECK (Conditions IN ('P(Proof)','BU(Brilliant Un-Circulated)','UC (Un-circulated)','VF (Very Fine)','F(Fine)','G (Good)','P(Poor)')),
   CONSTRAINT chk_Cointypes CHECK (Cointypes IN ('P' , 'N','D','Q','HD','D'))
) ;
```

Comment: Hey that worked and the table was I created. Thank you so much. Now I just need to input some data.